# Android - Samsung Galaxy S4 Reboot issue

Tags: android, android-camera, samsung-mobile, video-recording

I am an android developer who is making an app that uses a camera feature.
Recently, I updated my app to support GS4. 
I tested it on my GS4 and it worked fine. Both front and back camera.
However, it seems like some users's phone restarts after the record a video with my app.
I googled and found this article..

http://www.phonesreview.co.uk/2013/05/14/samsung-galaxy-s4-rebooting-issues-emerge-needs-update-fix/

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2271227

It seems like some users are having this issue and it seems related to Samsung's issue not mine. Normally when app has a problem, doesn't it force close instead of rebooting?
If the device reboots after crash, doesnt it mean that something went wrong on the system (OS) side?

I don't know if samsung has fixed this issue or not.. Anyone knows?
What should I do to deal with this issue? Let the user wait for samsung to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is part of the OS's memory managment at kernel level , if you look at the s4's ram usage you will see it is always extremely high above normal usage even when all apps are closed it averages above 1 GB...The OS reboots to free up space since the RAM is overflowed so  there is no problem with your app it is just samsung that has to admit to the problem and fix it with OTA.:)